# Shorter string causes the webpage to freeze

Tags: javascript, methods, html

When the HTML Chart button is pressed it activates the createChart() method. However, if the value in the textarea is 25 characters or less, the webpages freezes. Also, only the letter "a" is being referenced with the method.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
orangeBar = "./orange.gif";

function createChart()
    {

    alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    textValue = document.getElementById("text").value;
    max = 0;

    for (i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) 
    {
        value = numberOf(alphabet[i], textValue);
        if (value > max)
        {
            max = value;
        }
    }

    document.write(max);

}  

function numberOf(letter, string)
{
    count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<string.length; i++)
    {
        if (string[i].toLowerCase() == letter)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
</script>
```

Thank you. I'm brand new to coding. I can answer any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for (i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++)`, `i` becomes a global variable. Then you use the same `i` in `for (i=0; i<string.length; i++)` and it changes you `i` of the `createChart()` function. Put `var` before `i` to make it local.

```
for (var i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++)
```

and

```
for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++)
```

Comment: In fact, you should use var for all this variables - count, max, ... http://scribu.net/blog/javascript-var-keyword-for-php-developers.html

Comment: Good lord... Thank you so much! <3